# Containerizing vim with plugins

Tags: docker, vim, singularity-container

I am trying to containerize vim along with the plugins. I am using singularity containers. The most important plugin is [youcompleteme](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe). My approach to containerizing the plugins is to install vim and clone all the plugins to `/etc/vim/plugin` and compile youcompleteme during the build.
Once the image is built, I launch vim with the modified `runtimepath (rtp)` that points to /`etc/vim`:

> singularity run vim_image.sif vim --cmd 'set rtp^=/etc/vim'

But, vim is failing to load the plugins. I am getting errors like:

> Error detected while processing
> /etc/vim/plugin/sonokai/autoload/airline/themes/sonokai.vim: line
> 10: E117: Unknown function: sonokai#get_configuration line   11: E121:
> Undefined variable: s:configuration E116: Invalid arguments for
> function sonokai#get_palette(s:configuration.style,
> s:configuration.colors_override)
>
> ...

I expect vim to load any plugins inside `/etc/vim/plugin` without any issues. I am stuck on this. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this command:

```
sudo docker run -it amine2029/vim-plug
```

I build it using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl -yq \
    && apt-get install -yq vim git 
RUN curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim 

ADD vimrc /root/.vimrc

RUN vim -E -s -u "$HOME/.vimrc" +PlugInstall +qall
```

This 'vimrc' file need to be in the building directory (add more plugins here):

```
call plug#begin()
 Plug 'tomlion/vim-solidity'
call plug#end()
```

then to build:

```
sudo docker build -t vim-plug .
```

Answer (score 1):

> install vim and clone all the plugins to `/etc/vim/plugin`

This wouldn't work, even on a physical machine.

Vim's runtime files are laid out in a specific way that is expected to be consistent at all levels so putting your files in random arbitrary locations won't do you any good because nothing will be where it is expected to be.

In this specific case, `plugin/sonokai/autoload/airline/themes/sonokai.vim` is an autoloaded script but, because you naïvely put it under `plugin/`, it is sourced as a *global plugin*, which can only create trouble.

Vim allows you to create directory hierarchies under `plugin/` for organisational purpose but those subdirectories are for *global plugins* only. Filetype plugins, syntax scripts, indent scripts, autoloaded scripts, etc. have nothing to do there so they must be moved under the appropriate directory: `ftplugin/`, `syntax/`, etc.

That mechanism leads to a situation where, for a given third-party plugin `foo` you would get files scattered around:

```
plugin/foo/foo.vim
syntax/foo/foo.vim
       bar/bar.vim
indent/foo/foo.vim
       bar/bar.vim
etc.
```

It works, technically, and it might even be usable if you don't have too many plugins, but it is inherently messy.

Nowadays, the preferred way to handle plugins is via the newish `:help package` feature. Without spoiling the doc too much, there is a new directory in Vim's runtime called `pack` under which you can put whole third-party plugins, each in their own directory, which is basically what you are trying and failing to do in `plugin/`. So, instead of the layout above, you would have:

```
" one directory for plugin `foo`
pack/<whatever>/start/foo/plugin/foo.vim
                          indent/foo.vim
                          syntax/foo.vim
" and one directory for plugin `bar`
pack/<whatever>/start/bar/indent/bar.vim
                          syntax/bar.vim
```

In a normal setup for a normal user, that `pack` directory should be created under `$HOME/.vim/`. In this specific case, the right place is almost certainly `$VIM/vimfiles/`. The exact value of `$VIM` depends on many things so you will have to ask Vim where it is with:

```
:echo $VIM
```

and adjust your installation script accordingly.

---

I am not sure about the benefits of containerizing Vim, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not able to comment, I'll leave these here.
You can see how others do it in the most popular vim distribution SpaceVim.

1. [SpaceVim Docker install](https://spacevim.org/quick-start-guide/#run-in-docker)
2. [SpaceVim Docker repo](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/tree/master/docker)
3. [other simple example](https://github.com/drvim/drvim)